# Hibernate Map throws - ORA-01722: invalid number error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a simple program using Map with Hibernate. I have a Country entity with a Map of State's. Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "id")
    private Map<String, State> states;
// setters & getters
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
// setters & getters
}
```

Here is my program that creates some countries and states:

```
public class AppTest {
    private static final SessionFactory concreteSessionFactory;
        static {
         try {
                concreteSessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
          } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
          }
        }
        public static Session getSession()
                throws HibernateException {
            return concreteSessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        public static void main(String... args){
            saveCountries();
            showCountries();
       }

        private static void saveCountries() {
            saveCountry("US", "CA", "Texas");
            saveCountry("UK", "London", "Cambridge");           
        }

        private static void saveCountry(String countryName, String... states) {
            Session session=getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            Country country = new Country();
            country.setName(countryName);

            Map<String,State> stateMap = new HashMap<String, State>();
            int count = 0;
            for (String stateName : states) {
                State state = new State();
                state.setName(stateName);
                stateMap.put(stateName+ count++, state);
            }
            country.setStates(stateMap);
            session.save(country);
            session.close();
        }

        private static void showCountries() {
            Session session=getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Country c=(Country)session.get(Country.class, new Integer(1));
            Map<String,State> states = c.getStates();
            Iterator entries = states.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String,State> entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
                String key = entry.getKey();
                State value = (State)entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value.getName());
            }
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

When I try to run this program then I am getting exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.hibernate.examples.State#0]
```

I am getting this exception at line `session.save(country);` Please let me know why I am getting this error?

**Update:**

Based on answer given by JB, now I added `@GeneratedValue` to my Id's in Country and State. This time I started getting exception as:

```
Aug 22, 2014 1:44:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1722, SQLState: 42000
Aug 22, 2014 1:44:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Also below are DDL and DML operations that Hibernate has generated:

```
Hibernate: create table Country (id number(10,0) not null, name varchar2(255 char), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table state (id number(10,0) not null, name varchar2(255 char), country_id number(10,0), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table state add constraint FK_lxoqjm8644epv72af3k3jpalx foreign key (country_id) references Country
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence
Aug 22, 2014 1:44:49 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into Country (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into state (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into state (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update state set country_id=?, id=? where id=?
```

I am not clear on where I am still missing.

Comment: Have you implemented the equals and hashCode of the Entities?

Comment: No, I am following the example given here - http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-mapkeycolumn-hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your State entity has an ID that is not autogenerated. And you always create states without specifying any ID. So all your states have the same ID: 0. Hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks JB, adding GeneratedValue annotation has fixed the issue with `NonUniqueObjectException`, now I started getting different error (updated my post accordingly). Can you please help me how can I fix this?

Comment: You mapped the key of the map, or type String, to the column ID of the state, which is the column also used for the integer ID of the state. Use another column name in MapKeyColumn.